# How to appear two Stripe Element on a single page

Tags: javascript, html, stripe-payments

I would like to use two payment forms(stripe.js) on the same html. Only one if can be specified, so the payment form that is called first will be appeared, but the another will not.

Is there any ways to implement?

> The Stripe Element will be mounted to the first one.

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

// first one -> appeared
<div id="card-number-element"></div>


// another one -> not appeared
<div id="card-number-element"></div>

<script>
var cardNumberElement = elements.create("cardNumber");
if (document.getElementById("card-number-element")) {
  cardNumberElement.mount("#card-number-element");
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that Stripe will let you to create multiple card number elements in one form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problems with your code:

1. There should never be multiple HTML elements with the same `id` on the same page so this is incorrect HTML. (It will not break the page but as you see in the next step it'll cause confusion)

```
<div id="card-number-element"></div>
<div id="card-number-element"></div>
```

2. `document.getElementById` will always just return a single element. So `document.getElementById("card-number-element")` will only return the first element. Even when there are two.

### One possible solution:

1. use unique `id` values. Like `card-number-element-1` and `card-number-element-2`
2. Enable selecting both elements. So maybe we add the same `class` to both elements and use `getElementsByClasName` to select them both.
3. Now the only question that remains is how `cardNumberElement.mount` works - does it require a unique identifier per element? Let me just GUESS that it might. So I'm gonna have a unique `id` per element and pass that to the `mount` function.

Here's my attempt.

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

<div id="card-number-element-1"></div>
<div id="card-number-element-2"></div>

<script>
var cardNumberElement = elements.create("cardNumber");
var elementsToMountTo = document.getElementsByClassName("card-number-element");

elementsToMountTo.forEach((element) => {
   cardNumberElement.mount("#" + element.id);
}
</script>
```

PS: I have not looked into how Stripe works so I dunno if the line `cardNumberElement.mount` will work if you run it two times like this.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with Stripe Elements.  If you try two create two of the same type of Element (like the `card` Element) on the same page you will get this error:

```
Can only create one Element of type card
```

You would need to use a single Card Element, use separate pages, use `<iframe>` elements, or something along those lines as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with Stripe a few times but not done this before, this might work for you or give you an idea on moving forward..

The **html id** has to be unique on the page. That's why only the first one is getting made.

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

// first one
<div id="card-number-element-1"></div>


// another one
<div id="card-number-element-2"></div>

<script>
var cardNumberElement = elements.create("cardNumber");
if (document.getElementById("card-number-element-1")) {
  cardNumberElement.mount("#card-number-element-1");
}
if (document.getElementById("card-number-element-2")) {
  cardNumberElement.mount("#card-number-element-2");
}
</script>
```

This might not work with Stripe however, not sure if they support multiple elements like this.

Answer (score 0):

I did this by unmounting the current one and mounting the new one:

```
stripe = Stripe(publicKey);
var elements = stripe.elements();
var card = elements.create('card', { style: {} });
card.mount('#card-element'); // <<--- By this line the card will be created


$('#some-button').on('click', function() {
  card.unmount(); // <<--- By this line the current card will be disappeared
  card.mount('card-element-2'); // <<--- And lastly by this line your second card-element will be created here
});
```

And here you will do similar to the previous one but this time, the first card-element will be shown and the second one will be disappeared

```
$('#some-button').on('click', function() {
  card.unmount(); // <<--- By this line the second card will be disappeared
  card.mount('card-element'); // <<--- And lastly by this line your first card-element will be created here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Stripe allows only one mounted element.
You need to unmounted the first one to enable the second one.

HTML

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<form>
  <div class="group">
    <label>
      <span>Card 1</span>
      <div id="card-element-1" class="field"></div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <label>
      <span>Card 2</span>
      <div id="card-element-2" class="field"></div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <button id="toggle">Toggle card element</button>
  <button type="submit">Pay $25</button>
  <div class="outcome">
    <div class="error" role="alert"></div>
    <div class="success">
      Success! Your Stripe token is <span class="token"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh');
var elements = stripe.elements();

var currentMounted = '#card-element-1';

var card = elements.create('card', {
  style: {
    base: {
      iconColor: '#666EE8',
      color: '#31325F',
      lineHeight: '40px',
      fontWeight: 300,
      fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
      fontSize: '15px',

      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#CFD7E0',
      },
    },
  }
});
card.mount(currentMounted);

function setOutcome(result) {
  var successElement = document.querySelector('.success');
  var errorElement = document.querySelector('.error');
  successElement.classList.remove('visible');
  errorElement.classList.remove('visible');

  if (result.token) {
    // Use the token to create a charge or a customer
    // https://stripe.com/docs/charges
    successElement.querySelector('.token').textContent = result.token.id;
    successElement.classList.add('visible');
  } else if (result.error) {
    errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    errorElement.classList.add('visible');
  }
}

card.on('change', function(event) {
  setOutcome(event);
});

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = document.querySelector('form');
  stripe.createToken(card).then(setOutcome);
});

document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  card.unmount(currentMounted);
  if (currentMounted == '#card-element-1') {
    currentMounted = '#card-element-2';
  } else {
    currentMounted = '#card-element-1';
  }
  card.mount(currentMounted);
});
```

You can try my demo here: [Stripe : 2 forms on a single page](https://codepen.io/Rubyxcode/pen/MWXLerO)

Answer (score 0):

When implementing multiple elements (sets of input fields/forms) on one page, managing the mounting and unmounting of the stripe elements is the way to go.

It can be tricky because only one stripe element of a specific type can exist and be mounted within the javascript domain of the HTML page.

The good news however is that by using some Java scripting you can make it work and provide the end-user with a good and seamless experience.

So a possible route you could take ( *it worked for me* ) :

- First create all the stripe element objects you want to use

```
let stripe = Stripe('{your private key}');
let elements = stripe.elements();

elementsYouWantToUseInAnyForm.forEach( el => {
    stripe_element = elements.create(el.id, elementOptions);
});
```

- On your page you can now display the (unmounted) input areas of the different sets of input fields / forms and display the default placeholders. ( *In my case I use an 'Add a new card' form with `cardNumber, cardExpiry and cardCvC`, and for each existing card the customer already added in the past, a card form with only the `cardCvC` field* )
- You could now manage the unmounting of the 'current active' and the mounting of the, previously created, stripe elements when you want to activate (for example by clicking on a 'input' field area displaying the default placeholder) the specific elements set. You can restyle the elements you mount and provide the default placeholder using `element.update(elementOptions);`

This could look like :

```
function activateCardForm(cardFieldsToActivate) {
   // unmount the current active fields, and display the default placeholder
   currentCardFields.forEach(field => {
      field.stripe_element.unmount();
      field.displayDefaultPlaceholderInFieldArea();
   });
   // mount the new card, stripe will remove the placeholder and add the iframes
   currentCardFields = cardFieldsToActivate;
   currentCardFields.forEach(field => {
      field.stripe_element.update(field.elementOptions);
      stripe.mount("#"+field.mount_id);
   });
}
```

When you use this method make sure you show the default placeholders after fields are unmounted ( and the placeholder is, position-wise, matched with the placeholder of the stripe iframe, when mounted, the selecting of specific cards within one window/form is seamless for the end-user.

( *In my case I listen to the mouseclick on the default placeholder field and use `element.focus()` after the current (if any) elements are unmounted, default placeholder replaced and the new elements are mounted and the `element.on('ready', f);` is called.* )

If you are using field sets with full card setup (add a new card) or, re-using existing card (only using CvC), just only mount the stripe elements you need. If an element is not mounted, it will not be used and will not mess things up.

Just be sure to handle the `stripe.confirmCardPayment` correctly, so by passing the right paymentmethod field: `payment_method.card = cardNumberElement` for a full card and `payment_method = '{payment method (pm_) id}';` to CvC validate and pay with a previously added payment method.